# Ionic how to trunk or splice some data which is in tag

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a data which is look like this

```
It is worth noting that the Herzliya HILLS complex is a mixed-use complex, which means that, apart from 600 residential housing units, it also includes an office and commercial complex measuring 30,000 meters: "Half the office space is rented by  office.
<iframe src='http://anything.co.il/forms-iframes/?formid=5608&lm_form=28910&lm_key=e195d153df&title=%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9D&pageID=5603&pagetitle=%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99+%D7%94%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9D+%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A%3A+%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8+%D7%91%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A9+%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99' scrolling='no' width='100%' height='550'> <p>Sorry, this browser does not support iframes.</p> </iframe>
```

I need to hide data which will come in `<iframe>` the description of data will change some time its 100words some time 200. so i need to know how can i just remove the data which is in iframe tags ?

I'm simply showing in dive like this

```
<div  *ngIf="get" style="margin-right: 15px ;margin-left: 15px; text-align: right" [innerHTML]="get.content" dir="rtl"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is **everytime** on two lines, you can do this :

```html
<div> innerHTML="{{ get.content.split('\n')[1] }}" </div>
```

Otherwise, you could write a `Pipe` which truncates the string using Regular Expression :

```html
<div innerHtml="{{ get.content | iframe }}"></div>
```

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'iframe'})
export class IframePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string): string {
    let regexp = new RegExp('<iframe.*<\/iframe>');
    let result = regexp.exec(text);
    return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : '';
  }
}
```